# VS 2013 Store Create App Packages Disabled

Tags: php, ajax, cordova

I am trying to deploy a Windows Phone 8.0 package with VS 2013, in order to **Update** it to the Store but i am getting all menu of store is showing disable. what i am missing. i already upload this app on store . but after modified and test it i want to update my app but not able to create package . what i am missing. i am attaching my screen shot of VS 13.[image]